# Is there an IE Render Complete event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer-8

While trying to determine why a page was taking 20s to load, I found some odd behavior in IE8.

The scenario is this.

I make an ajax call, it returns and the callback looked something like this

```
$("#StoreDetailsContainer").html($(tableHtml));
var StoreDetailsTable = $("#StoreDetailsTable");
StoreDetailsTable.tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0]], cssChildRow: "SubTable" });
StoreDetailsTable.filtertable({ cssChildRow: "SubTable" });
```

However, this bit of code took 20s to complete.

I was messing around, timing things, and popping up alerts between methods, and suddenly, it took only 6s.  I played around a little more to find that if I introduced a delay after the `.html()` call, and before I attempted to manipulate the DOM, the page rendered MUCH faster.  It now looks like this

```
$("#StoreDetailsContainer").html($(tableHtml));
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var StoreDetailsTable = $("#StoreDetailsTable");
    StoreDetailsTable.tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0]], cssChildRow: "SubTable" });
    StoreDetailsTable.filtertable({ cssChildRow: "SubTable" });
}, 100);
```

It also only takes 6s despite having an extra 1/10th of a second added to the process.

My theory is that because the DOM wasn't fully rendered to the screen by IE by the `.html()` call before attempting to work with it, there is some kind of locking happening.

Is there a way to determine when IE has finished rendering what was added to the DOM by `.html()` so I don't need to use an arbitrary value in a `setTimeout` call?

Comment: IE 8 has a profiler built into its script debugger; why not use it?

Comment: Isn't this what `$(document).ready()` is for?

Comment: he calls a jquery function to insert the html... thus this would fire long before he needs it to

Comment: @Craig, I've looked into it, and haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: My wild guess is that doing the two operations together is making the reflow combine in a bad way. But hard to be sure from the description. But you should be able to test this. If so, it may be easier to fix than the timing issue.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz, I'm not trying to do two operations together.  I executed the operations one after another, but the `.html()` operation doesn't appear to be **done** when it returns and the subsequent steps are executed.  The DOM is updated, hence I can work with it, but IE is still rendering it, it would appear.

Comment: Then why not $("#StoreDetailsContainer").html($(tableHtml)).ready();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a single pixel image to your callback response, get that image from the DOM after .html(..) and attach to its onload event.  I can't imagine it's possible for the image's onload event to fire until the browser has rendered it.

Make sure the image has a unique identifier in the src so that it doesn't get cached...

Odd problem you're having though - I'm sure someone will offer a more graceful solution :)

B

Comment: I'm kind of conflicted here - part of me wants to say I hope you get it to work - most of me says I hope you don't have to :)

Comment: I agree.  I shouldn't have to mess with quirks of a browser.

Comment: this technique seems to work.  Hopefully there is a better way though.

Answer (score 6):

You're almost on the spot with your analysis. Let me attempt to explain why `setTimeout` is making the difference.

If you look at this great [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20121120093321/http://blog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/12/12/understanding-internet-explorer-rendering-behaviour/) about DOM rendering, you'll understand that `.html()` will cause a ***reflow*** to happen.

Now with the  next two lines, what is happening is that you're tying up the browser's rendering thread. Browsers may choose to wait till script execution completes before attempting a reflow (to avoid multiple reflows or to buffer all changes).

The solution - we need to tell the browser that our `html` changes are done and you can complete the rendering process. The way to do it - 1) end your script 2) use `setTimeout` to yield the execution to the browser.

Doing a `setTimeout` with 0ms delay also works because `setTimeout` basically relinquishes control of the sript block. One of the reasons why animation related script rely so heavily on `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

Another potential improvement would be to use `documentFragments`, explained succinctly by John Resig [here](https://johnresig.com/blog/dom-documentfragments/)

I think combining these two should yield more speed but of course, no way to know until profiling is done!

Answer (score 2):

Calling `setTimeout` delays the given function at least for the specified time but it is never run before the current script execution finished. That said, you could replace your timeout with 0 seconds.

Another approach that might be worth trying is that you access some layout property of the generated content (for example height of *StoreDetailsContainer*). This way you force IE to finish rendering before returning control to your script since it can only provide the correct value that your script requested after finishing to calculate the layout.

Third guess that might help is that you ensure to parse the HTML out-with the page's layout. This would prevent painting half-done layouts over and over again. To do so, you could detach the *StoreDetailsContainer* element from the DOM prior your call to `html`. Now, IE has the change to construct the DOM without affecting the layout. After that you would re-append the *StoreDetailsContainer* into the DOM. Compared to a normal `innerHTML` set, this detaching and re-attaching of the container allows you to control when the HTML is parsed to build the DOM tree and when the layout is calculated.

Comment: you mention that setTimeout code isn't run until after the current script execution.  Do you have documentation for that?

Comment: See [HTML 5, section 7.3 Timers, step 8](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers). Probably Mozilla refers to the additional delay when they say _busy with other tasks_ on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

I've set up [a example](http://jsfiddle.net/KuL72/) to have more than theory. You'll find the following order of events (on calls to `console.timeEnd`: delayed, whole, timeout, timeout long. Note especially that _timeout_ is printed after _whole_ despite the time limit is shorter. There is only one script running at a time.

Comment: I read that MDC document too.  But since it doesn't specifically say that is how it works, despite it appearing as such now, it's an implementation detail that I'd rather not rely on.  As browsers become more advanced it's highly likely that they start using more threads, and this behavior changes so that setTimeout fires when the timeout is elapsed, not just when the timeout is elapsed AND the calling script has completed.

Comment: If you think about it, it makes sense. Another function can't be running parallel to the current function in javascript:
window.graph=createLargeObjectGraph();
for(var i=0;i<10;++i)
  setTimeout(randomlyTraverseAndModifyLargeObjectGraph(),0);
wasteMilliseconds(1000);
console.log(window.graph);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. The load event is fired after ready event, so it may work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#StoreDetailsContainer").html($(tableHtml))
  });
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#StoreDetailsTable").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0]], cssChildRow: "SubTable" }).filtertable({ cssChildRow: "SubTable" });
  });
```

Comment: That won't work, as this isn't loaded with the page, or right after, it's much later.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it could work like this:

```
$("#StoreDetailsContainer").html($(tableHtml))
.find("#StoreDetailsTable")
.tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0]], cssChildRow: "SubTable" })
.filtertable({ cssChildRow: "SubTable" });
```