# How to achieve atomic operations ( Concurrency model ) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, dom-events

Say, I want to increment a counter every time I get an ajax response. I don't know about the concurrency model with JavaScript async events. Any thoughts?

Comment: See the comments [on an answer to another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944748/is-there-an-ie-render-complete-event/6987573#6987573). Essentially, all scripts are lined up for execution and there are never 2 script running at the same time. If a script is executing, newly triggered scripts (triggered on user caused events or by AJAX requests) are put to a queue. Therefore there are no concurrency issues in JavaScript since no concurrency is available.

Comment: What do you mean by no two scripts execute at the same time. What exactly counts as a unit of script in your defintion ?

Comment: I guess what is meant by "script" must be the entire response, on the part of all the JavaScript that has been loaded, to a given event.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Within a browser, there is only ever one javascript thread running at a time.

Concurrency issues are possible in that while an ajax response is pending, javascript may run in response to an unrelated event. But you are safe if you do not start an operation intended to be atomic before an ajax call and finish it in the response handler.

Comment: Yes. Every event is handled atomically.